# Atomically writing and reading file from iOS shared container directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-locking

I have this simple scenario: an App and one of its extensions have to access the same file (stored in their shared container). The App can write to the file while the extension only reads from it.

I don't find Apple documentation very clear on the subject, especially:

> You can use CFPreferences, atomic safe save operations on flat files, or SQLite or Core Data to share data in a group container between multiple processes even if one is suspended mid transaction.

taken from:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2408/_index.html

Does the "atomic safe save operations on flat files" part mean that if I write the file with

```
[ array writeToURL: fileUrl atomically: YES ]
```

and read it with

```
[[ NSArray alloc ] initWithContentsOfURL: fileUrl ]
```

I should be okay without using any file-level locking mechanism?

Thanks in advance,
Francesco